# Cannot duplicate ember model

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to copy an object from the controller "content"?

I've tried adding Ember.Copyable mixin in the model :

```
App.Template = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Copyable, {
   id : "0",
   title : "test"
}
```

In my controller I would like to copy the model that has been injected in the route.

```
this.set('datas',Ember.copy(this.get('content'));
```

I get this error when data-binding the datas object :

**Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.**

Can you provide an answer without using ember-data ?

Comment: Could it be that the "content" has not loaded yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to implement the copy method yourself as per [Ember.Copyable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Copyable.html).

Here's an example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lekox/3/edit